# Database Group By error

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working with Mysql for a while, but this is the first time I've encountered this problem.

The thing is that I have a select query...

```
SELECT
    transactions.inventoryid,
    inventoryName,
    inventoryBarcode,
    inventoryControlNumber,
    users.nombre,
    users.apellido,
    transactionid,
    transactionNumber,
    originalQTY,
    updateQTY,
    finalQTY,
    transactionDate,
    transactionState,
    transactions.observaciones
FROM
    transactions
LEFT JOIN 
    inventory ON inventory.inventoryid = transactions.inventoryid
LEFT JOIN 
    users ON transactions.userid = users.userid
GROUP BY
    transactions.transactionNumber
ORDER BY
    transactions.inventoryid
```

But the GROUP BY is eliminating 2 values from the QUERY.

In this case, when I output:

```
foreach($inventory->inventory as $values){
    $transactionid[] = $values['inventoryid'];
}
```

It returns:

```
2,3,5
```

If I eliminate the GROUP BY Statement it returns

```
2,3,4,5,6
```

Which is the output I need for this particular case.

The question is:

Is there a reason for this to happen?
If I'm grouping by a transaction and that was supposed to affect the query, wouldn't it then return only 1 value?

Maybe I'm over thinking this one or been working too long on the code that I don't see the obvious flaw in my logic.  But if someone can lend me a hand I would appreciate it.

Comment: if `4`/`6` are not returned with the `GROUP BY` clause, then they have the same `transactionNumber` as one of the early returned rows. It also means you have 3 distinct `transactionNumber` in your table.

Comment: That's the thing, they all have the same transactionNumber, even 2,3,5

Comment: no. they don't. they can't. if you are grouping by a thing, you get one row per thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard SQL you can only `SELECT` colums which are

- contained in `GROUP BY` clause
- (or) aggregate "colums", like `MAX()` or `COUNT()`.

You need to consult the MySQL description of the interpretation they use for columns which are not contained by `GROUP BY` (and which are no aggregated column) [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) to find out what happens here.

Do you need more information?

Comment: If this information solves the probem, you may check this as correct answer. :)